# JPA criteria query, order on class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is there a way with JPA criteria queries to order on **class**? Imagine the following domain objects:

```
abstract class Hobby { ... }
class Coding extends Hobby { ... }
class Gaming extends Hobby { ... }
```

Using regular QL I was able to do

```
from Hobby h order by h.class
```

But when I apply the same logic on a criteria query, the runtime exception "unknown attribute" occurs.

```
CriteriaQuery<Hobby> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Hobby.class);
Root<Hobby> hobbyRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Hobby.class);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.asc(hobbyRoot.get("class"));
List<Hobby> hobbies = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

JPA implementation used: Hibernate-EntityManager v3.5.5-Final

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JPA 2.0 introduces a new `TYPE` expression that allow a query to restrict results based on class types.

You can use a type expression with the Criteria API using `Path#type()`. So you could *try*:

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Hobby.class);
Root hobbyRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Hobby.class);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.asc(hobbyRoot.type());
List hobbies = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

While this code compiles, I didn't test it (I'll give it a try tomorrow).

Actually, I wonder if this is legal or if the `type()` should be part of the select in order to `order by` it (maybe that's what the criteria query is supposed to generate). Need to check that.

#### References

- JPA 2.0 specification

  - Section 4.6.17.4 "Entity Type Expressions"

#### More resources

- [Java Persistence 2.0 Proposed Final Draft](http://blogs.oracle.com/ldemichiel/entry/java_persistence_2_0_proposed)

Comment: thanks, too bad hibernate they didn't implement it properly yet. http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4881

Comment: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4881 has been resolved in hibernate 4.0.0