# How do I tell JPA CriteriaBuilder to order by the only column of data returned?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by, jpa-2.1

I’m using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate 4.3.6.Final (MySQL 5.5).  In my JPA CriteriaBuilder query, my only column returned is a expression that ultimately evaluates to an Integer.  However, how do I tell JPA to order the results based on the first column alone?  I have …

```
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Integer> criteria = builder.createQuery(Integer.class);
    final Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
    criteria.where(builder.and(builder.like(user.get(User_.userName), userNamePrefix + "%"),
                               builder.equal(user.get(User_.url), url)));

    criteria.select( builder.substring(user.get(User_.userName), userNamePrefix.length()).as(Integer.class) );
    criteria.orderBy( ??? );
```

What do I put in “???” to tell JPA to order on the only column of data returned?  I realize I could get all columns and use Java to sort, but I would like to avoid that at the moment.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
Expression selectedExpr = builder.substring(user.get(User_.userName);
criteria.select(selectedExpr, userNamePrefix.length()).as(Integer.class));
Order orderExpr = builder.asc(selectedExpr);
criteria.orderBy(orderExpr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the criteriaBuilder to build an Order object for me. ie

`criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(user.get(User_.userNmae)));`

Similar question and more detailed answer : [JPA criteria query, order on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188397/jpa-criteria-query-order-on-class)